# Spatially-structured photons

Tags: photons, speed-of-light

An article posted back in 2015 at [Physics World](http://physicsworld.com/cws/article/news/2015/jan/22/structured-photons-slow-down-in-a-vacuum) says:

> Over two years, Miles Padgett and colleagues at the University of
>   Glasgow, together with Daniele Faccio of Heriot-Watt University in
>   Edinburgh, designed an experiment that can determine whether light
>   with a certain "spatial structure" travels substantially slower than
>   regular light in a vacuum. The researchers created a source that
>   emitted pairs of photons simultaneously. One of the photons went
>   straight to a highly precise photon counter, while the other went via
>   two liquid-crystal masks, which imparted their profile onto the
>   passing particle of light.
>
> Across a propagation distance of 1 m, the team found that the
>   spatially structured photon lagged behind its partner by between 10
>   and 20 wavelengths. That equated to a drop in speed of about 0.001%,
>   says team member Jacquiline Romero.

Since a spatially-structured photon travels slower than a photon that hasn't passed through the liquid-crystal masks, does this mean it's possible to slow down photons even further to say about the speed of sound?

Answer (score 0):

Photons travel at a set speed. They take twice as long travelling through glass as through air because of the crystalline structure of glass which forces them to take a much longer path.

Light takes 0.01% longer to travel through air than through a vacuum so why would anyone expect it to travel as fast through a denser medium like a liquid crystal mask?

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. The article makes it clear that by photons passing through this liquid-crystal mask, it becomes spatially-structured and *remains that way in a vacuum*. In other words, a medium isn't continuously keeping it slowed down like slow light, which requires a medium to slow down significantly and remain that way. I'm asking if the speed can be slowed further than having a drop in speed of about 0.001%.

Comment: Glass has an amorphous structure and not a crystalline